# How can i solve this unique key prop error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

{users.map((user) => (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>{user._id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{user.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{user.email}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{user.hobby}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button>Edit</Button>
                <Button>Delete</Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
```

Please help me solve this error

Comment: Have you spent some time with seeing [Docs / search online](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) ?

Comment: `<TableRow key={user._id}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are iterating over the array, so you can capture the unique item from the array to make it as a key, and key also need to be unique, so here in the above code, the id is unique, so you can write like this,

```
{users.map((user) => (
        <TableRow key={user._id}>
          <TableCell>{user._id}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{user.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{user.email}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{user.hobby}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <Button>Edit</Button>
            <Button>Delete</Button>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
```